How to Find Closest Average for a set of variables from Multiple Sets of Numbers
I'm working on a problem where I have several sets of numbers and I need to find the closest average for a set of target values by combining numbers from these sets.
For example, let's say I want to achieve the following target averages:
x = 5
y = 10

I have two sets of numbers:
a = {2, 8, 4, 15, 3, 6, 5}
b = {5, 2, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2}

To illustrate, if I combine the first and second index from set aa, I get an average for xx as:
x = (2 + 8) / 2 = 5

However, if I use these indices, the corresponding values from set b give an average for y as:
y = (5 + 2) / 2 = 3.5

The objective is to find combinations of up to 256 different indices (absolutely no more) from these sets to get the closest possible average to the target values for all variables. My actual data sets are much larger than the example provided.
I am looking for a method or algorithm to efficiently find the best combination of indices to get the closest approximation to my target averages.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

indices can be used twice

Suppose one set of indices gets $\bar x$ somewhat close and $\bar y$ very close, and another set of indices gets $\bar x$ very close and $\bar y$ somewhat close.  How do you decide which set of indices is better?

This is my understanding of the question. OP has $N$ finite sequences of numbers, each the same length $K$, say $s_i = {s_{i1}, s_{i2}, \dots s_{iK}}$.  Each  sequence $s_i$ also has an associated target value $t_i$.  OP wants to choose a single vector of weights $w_1\ldots w_K$, with $W=\sum w_i$ no more than $256$, such that for the $i$th sequence, the weighted mean $$\bar{s_i} = \frac1W\sum_{j=1}^K w_i s_{ij}$$ is as close to $t_i$ as possible.  It's not clear yet how one measures the overall closeness of the set of $\bar{s_i}$ to the targets $t_i$ since there is more than one.

I would just take the sum of all the errors and use the smallest result to find the 'closest'

Here is an integer optimization approach, I hope for a faster approach.
Suppose you have $r$ such sets and the targets are $t_j$.
Let the list be $A_j = [A_{j1}, A_{j2}, \ldots, A_{jk}]$.
Let $x_i$ be a nonnegative integer indicating how many times index $i$ is chosen.
We want to impose condition that $1 \le \sum x_i \le 256$ and we want $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k A_{ji}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^kx_i}$ to be close to $t_j$.
One possible formulation is we want $|\sum_{i=1}^k (A_{ji}-t_j) x_i|$ to be small for each $j$.
Let say we want to minimize $\sum_{j=1}^r |\sum_{i=1}^k (A_{ji}-t_j) x_i|$.
One possible formulation is
$$\min \sum_{j=1}^r y_j$$
subject to $$y_j \ge \sum_{i=1}^k (A_{ji}-t_j) x_i, \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, r\}$$
$$y_j \ge \sum_{i=1}^k -(A_{ji}-t_j) x_i, \forall j \in \{1, \ldots, r\}$$
$$1 \le \sum x_i \le 256$$
$$x_i \ge 0, x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Of course, one doesn't have to use the sum of absolute value as the measure. Depending on the optimization criteria, we can come out with different formulation.
